# Key Error while sorting column in Pivot dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

Refer the data frame screenshot [df10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ap241.png)

I have tried all options / solutions available to sort the pivot by year colum '2019'. However I am getting the following error.

```
KeyError: '2019'
```

Few lines above this error says :

```
*1690             values = self.axes[axis].get_level_values(key)._values
1691         else:
-> 1692             raise KeyError(key)
1693 
1694         # Check for duplicates*
```

I am using the following code

```
df10 = df10.sort_values('2019' , ascending=False)
```

I thought there is whitespace in the column so used below code as well and got the error

```
df10.columns=df10.columns.str.strip()

Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

Here is the output of

```
print (df10.columns.tolist())
[2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019]
```

Comment: Your column labels aren't strings (notice no apostrophes around what `df10.columns` is showing you - they're actual numbers... do `df10[2019]` for instance...

Comment: Now getting error KeyError: CLINIC_updated Tried this df10 = df10.sort_values(df10[2019] , ascending=False)

Comment: Okay...so you don't want to give it a series for sort_values, you just want: `df10.sort_values(2019 , ascending=False)`

Comment: Great. Worked. I spent more than 1 hour on this error itself. Thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue with column names having blank after creating pivot and I was using without blanks in sort_values. Once I strip column values, it all worked.